# modal wont close can someone check whats wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

my modal seems to be working all ok except for the close button its throwing undefined error and i am unable to close the modal when click on the link.

would really appreciate if someone here could help me out fixing it. i just cannot seem to get where i am going wrong.

here is my complete code and also fiddle for the code is  https://jsfiddle.net/j6xt5eok/

```
<style>

.modal-dialog {
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}

.customs-info a {
    background-color: #f00;
    display: block;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 25px auto 0;
    padding: 15px 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 14px;
}

#boxes {
    display: block;
}
#boxes #dialog {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#boxes .window {
    display: block;
    width: 100% !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    top: 0px !important;
}
.home-page-popup .close {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    opacity: .75;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 12px;
    text-indent: 0;
    top: 12px;
    width: 30px;
}
.close {
    float: right;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #000;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
    opacity: .2;
}
.content_bx {
    background: #fff;
    height: calc(100vh - 80px);
    width: 100%;
}
.main_img_ct {
    padding: 20px 0 10px 0px;
}
.main_img_ct {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    padding: 20px 0 50px 0px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.cont_bx2 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 15%;
}
.cont_bx2 h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #ff0000;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.cont_bx2 a {
    font-size: 22px;
}
.fa-2x {
    font-size: 30px !important;
    margin: 0 7px 0 0;
}
.cont_bx2 a {
    font-size: 31px;
    color: #009FF1;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    
    border-radius: 46px;
    line-height: normal;
    width: 68%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-shadow: #000 0 1px 1px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #009FF1;
}
.cont_bx2 h4 {
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #5F5F63 !important;
    font-family: mallory,helveticaneue-bold,helvetica neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    margin: 23px 0;
    
}

.cont_bx2 p strong {
    font-size: 22px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}
.cont_bx2 p {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: mallory,helveticaneue-bold,helvetica neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    color: #02416c;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.cont_bx2 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 15%;
}
.cont_bx2 p {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: mallory,helveticaneue-bold,helvetica neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    color: #02416c;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.lakdi_pn {
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.phon-img a img {
    width: 35%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    display:block;
}
.phon-img {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 23px;
}
.phon-img a {
    color: #000;
}
.modal-dialog {
    margin: 0;
}
.home-page-popup a#close_id img {
    width: 20px;
}

</style>

<div id="myModal" class="modal " role="dialog" style="display:block">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      
      
      
      <div id="boxes">
   <div class="home-page-popup">
      <div style="display: block;" id="dialog" class="window">
       <a href="javaScript:void(0);" data-dismiss="modal" id="close_id" onclick="close_dilog(this.id)" class="close">
         <img src="img/close-icon.png" alt="close" width="30" height="20"> </a> 
         <div class="popup-dsgn-box">
            <div class="content_bx">           
         
                  
                 <div class="main_img_ct">
                   
                <div class="cont_bx2">
                  <h1> For  Customer Service </h1>
                  
                  
                  
                 
   <a href="tel:+1 (000) 000-0000" style="">
<i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x"></i>+1 (000) 000-0000</a>


   <h4>EXCLUSIVE DEALS!</h4>
          
 <p style="color:#000 !important; padding:0 10px;"><strong>Call Us Now To Book,</strong> Change or Cancel Reservations and <strong>Get upto 50% OFF</strong></p>
                
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                      
                   
                    
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="phon-img">
                            <a href="tel:+1 (000) 000-0000">
                                <img src="img/mobile-phone.png" alt="mobile">
                                Click to Call
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                     <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="flat-address" style="text-align: center;">        
                               <div class="customs-info">                                
                                  <a href="tel:+1 (000) 000-0000" style="color:#fff;"> Call Now: <i class="fa fa-phone-square"></i> +1 (000) 000-0000 </a>                                
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /.top-navigator -->
                    </div><!-- /.col-md-4 -->              
                </div>             
              </div>    
          </div>
         
         </div>
      </div>
      <!--<div id="mask" style="display: block; width: 1349px; height: 2538px; opacity: 0.8;"></div>-->
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

thanks alot in advance, really appreciate your help

Comment: What is `close_dilog`? You have no javascript...

Comment: oh thanks got it :)